# Purpose of the sass-rails gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the purpose of the `gem 'sass-rails'` that is included by default in the `:assets` group of a new rails app ?

If I comment out that line I can still use `.css.scss` files without a problem.

Comment: Did you restart the server first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need it for sass/scss files.  Clear your browser cache, clear rails cache (`Rails.cache.clear` in console), comment out the line, uninstall the gem (all versions), then restart your server.  You'll get the following error:

```
no such file to load -- sass
```

Uncomment the line for the sass-rails gem, reinstall the gem and restart your server to make it work again.

Comment: Thanks. These steps are also helpful if you are using the `less-rails` gem instead of `sass-rails`.